# My leaflet map is showing blank space while collapsing the left panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, leaflet

I'm creating a portal, where am using leaflet map. But when I collapsing my left panel. it showing blank space. how to solve it. Also I have `invalidateSize()` function . but It's not working. Kindly let me know how to solve it.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    
    
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
         integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
         crossorigin=""/>
    
        <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
         integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
         crossorigin=""></script>
    
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
        <style>
            #map { height: 100%; }
    
            .box {
            }
    
            .left {
               width:20%;
               background:red;
               float:left;
            }
    
            .right {
                width:80%;
                background:green;
                 float:left;
            }
    
            .right-100 {
                 width:100%;
            }
    
            .left-0 {
                 width:0%;
            }
    
            .collapse {
                background:blue;
                color:white;
                width:100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse">collape it</div>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="left">
                Hello Shubham
            </div>
    
            <div class="right ">
                 <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        <script>
            var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    
            L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
                maxZoom: 18
            }).addTo(map);
    
            // Listen for the event that fires when the panel is collapsed
            document.getElementById("#collapse").addEventListener("click", function () {
                alert('sasASas');
                // Call the invalidateSize method to trigger a recalculation of the map's size
                map.invalidateSize();
            });
            
    
    
    
    
    
        </script>
    
        <script>
            $(document).on('click', '.collapse', function () {
                alert('SasASas');
                $('.right').addClass('right-100');
                $('.left').addClass('left-0')
            })
        </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, i hope it will work, just added map.invalidateSize(); in your document on click function.

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>


     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <style>
        #map { height: 100%; }

        .box {
        }

        .left {
           width:20%;
           background:red;
           float:left;
        }

        .right {
            width:80%;
            background:green;
             float:left;
        }

        .right-100 {
             width:100%;
        }

        .left-0 {
             width:0%;
        }

        .collapse {
            background:blue;
            color:white;
            width:100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="collapse" id="collapse">collape it</div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="left">
            Hello Shubham
        </div>

        <div class="right ">
             <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>









    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map);

    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.collapse', function () {
            alert('SasASas');
            $('.right').addClass('right-100');
            $('.left').addClass('left-0')
            map.invalidateSize();
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mc M.d. working very nicely , Thank You